# SUM a grouped column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sum the "Total Inservice Hours" for each user, but I am getting "Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function" with all my attempts. One attempt was wrapping a SUM() around the "Total Inservice Hours" field, then grouping by u.id.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT u.id,"Name",
atstat.grade,IFNULL(c.total_ceus,0) as max_ceus,c.id as courseid,atsess.id as sessid, count(c.total_ceus) as numsess, IFNULL(ROUND(((SUM(grade)/count(c.total_ceus))*total_ceus)/100,2),0) as "Total Inservice Hours"
FROM mdl_user u,mdl_course c
JOIN mdl_course_modules cm ON c.id = cm.course 
JOIN mdl_attendance_sessions atsess ON cm.instance = atsess.attendanceid
JOIN mdl_attendance_log atlog ON atlog.sessionid = atsess.id 
JOIN mdl_attendance_statuses atstat ON atstat.id = atlog.statusid 
WHERE u.id = atlog.studentid AND (u.id = 3882) AND c.total_ceus > 0
GROUP by u.id,c.id
ORDER BY u.id DESC LIMIT 300
```

Here is the result of that query:
[image]

I tried to GROUP BY u.id, but I got this result:
[image]

The only field I really care about is u.id and Total Inservice Hours. The rest are just there for debugging.

Desired output would be the sum of Total Inservice Hours, which would be 111 in this example.

Thanks!

Edit:
Invalid use of group function error SQL:

```
SELECT u.id,"Name",
atstat.grade,IFNULL(c.total_ceus,0) as max_ceus,c.id as courseid,atsess.id as sessid, count(c.total_ceus) as numsess, SUM(IFNULL(ROUND(((SUM(grade)/count(c.total_ceus))*total_ceus)/100,2),0)) as "Total Inservice Hours"
FROM mdl_user u,mdl_course c
JOIN mdl_course_modules cm ON c.id = cm.course 
JOIN mdl_attendance_sessions atsess ON cm.instance = atsess.attendanceid
JOIN mdl_attendance_log atlog ON atlog.sessionid = atsess.id 
JOIN mdl_attendance_statuses atstat ON atstat.id = atlog.statusid 
WHERE u.id = atlog.studentid AND (u.id = 3882) AND c.total_ceus > 0
GROUP by u.id
ORDER BY u.id DESC LIMIT 300
```

Comment: Please show the query that gets the error.

Comment: you can tell this is mysql because any other database would have returned an error while MySQL does the wrong thing happily instead.    General rule, if it's in the select line and not an aggregate, then it must be in the group by clause.  Are yo looking to return data fields with the aggregates?

Comment: @Barmar Posted the SQL that generated an error.

Comment: I think the last value of `total_ceus` referenced in the Total Inservice Hours expression is just an arbitrary value from the results because you have not applied an aggregate to it. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't wrap one aggregate function around another.

You need to put your original query in a subquery, in order to sum one of its columns. And since you're only interested in the ID and Total Inservice Hours, you can leave out the other `SELECT` columns.

```
SELECT id, SUM(`Total Inservice Hours`) AS "Total Inservice Hours"
FROM (SELECT u.id, IFNULL(ROUND(((SUM(grade)/count(c.total_ceus))*total_ceus)/100,2),0) as "Total Inservice Hours"
    FROM mdl_user u,mdl_course c
    JOIN mdl_course_modules cm ON c.id = cm.course 
    JOIN mdl_attendance_sessions atsess ON cm.instance = atsess.attendanceid
    JOIN mdl_attendance_log atlog ON atlog.sessionid = atsess.id 
    JOIN mdl_attendance_statuses atstat ON atstat.id = atlog.statusid 
    WHERE u.id = atlog.studentid AND (u.id = 3882) AND c.total_ceus > 0
    GROUP by u.id,c.id
    ORDER BY u.id DESC LIMIT 300) AS subq
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks! Have a mighty bad headache combined with not using SQL in over a week made me forget about subqueries.